# Javascript enum: How to do a lookup by property value?

Tags: javascript, enumeration

I have an enumeration defined like this:

```
module.exports = {
    APP_TYPES: {
        TYPE_ONE: { id: 5, name: "Application One name"},
        TYPE_TWO: { id: 9, name: "Application Two name"},
        TYPE_THREE: { id: 6, name: "Application Three name"}
    }
}
```

I want to be able to reverse lookup the enum based on property values.

```
   lookupById: function(id) {
       for (var app in this.APP_TYPES) {
           if(this.APP_TYPES.hasOwnProperty(app) && app.id === id) {
                return app;
            }
       }
    }
```

It appears that I cannot access the 'id' property of the enums. How do I refactor this so that I can access the properties defined on the enums?

Comment: you can access the property just fine, you just need to do `this.APP_TYPES[app].id` rather than just `app.id`. I'd also point out that what you're dealing with here is not an enum, but rather a simple javascript Object

Comment: Hamms is right. `app` is `TYPE_ONE`, etc., rather than `{ id: 5, name: "Application One name"}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `app` is the key on the `APP_TYPES` object, you have to access `APP_TYPES[app]` to get the object which has the `id` property

```
lookupById: function(id) {
    for (var app in this.APP_TYPES) {
        if(this.APP_TYPES.hasOwnProperty(app) && this.APP_TYPES[app].id === id) {
             return app;
         }
    }
 }
```